# Навигация по сайту и просмотренные слайды сохранённые в истории браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Есть слайдер на Owl Carousel 2.1.1.

Когда листаешь слайды, а потом пытаешься перейти на предыдущую страницу с помощью кнопки "назад" в самом браузере, браузер открывает прошлый слайд.

Все просмотренные слайды сохраняются в истории браузера, что очень затрудняет навигацию по сайту.

Код:

```js
$('.slider-cart-sub').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: false,
    items: 4,
    dots: false,
    merge: true,
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme slider-cart-sub">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="{{ photo.image.url }}" data-fancybox="group">
      <img class="cart-sub-item-img" src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="{{ item.name }}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

В документации ничего про это не сказано, поиск по гуглу результатов не дал.

Comment: Вам нужно не сохранять последний просмотренный слайд?

Comment: У меня не получилось это воспороизвести. Где можно увидеть воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: Для перехода использовать [Location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OwlCarousel` здесь ни при чём.
`Url` меняет `Fancybox`. Если хотите отключить изменение в адресной строке (что и пишется в историю браузера) укажите в настройках fancybox опцию `hash: false`
[Документация Fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options)